# How to replace the deprecated repeatWhen(notifier) with repeat(delay)

Tags: rxjs, onclick, delay, repeat

While testing, refactoring and future-proofing a customers project, I stumbled over this little deprecation notification:

> Will be removed in v9 or v10. Use repeat's delay option instead.
>
> repeatWhen(notifier: (notifications: Observable) =>
> Observable): MonoTypeOperatorFunction

Simple enough, right? But when I tried, I didn't find a simple way to do so. I have a rough idea how I could hack it. But that's not exactly what I'd like to hand over to a customer as "improved" code. So what obvious path do I fail to see, that leads from this (straight out of the rxjs documentation):

```js
import { of, fromEvent, repeatWhen } from 'rxjs';

const source = of('Repeat message');
const documentClick$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');

***const result = source.pipe(repeatWhen(() => documentClick$));***

result.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

to this:

```js
import { of, fromEvent, repeat } from 'rxjs';

const source = of('Repeat message');
const documentClick$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');

const result = source.pipe(repeat({ delay: ??? () => documentClick$) });

result.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

How to switch an option that accepts a number into an option that repeats whenever the event happens? Well, as said, I have an idea how to achieve it, but it would be incredibly ugly. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, just remove the question marks :)

```
source.pipe(repeat({ delay: () => documentClick$ }));
```

This basically says "Whenever `source` completes, subscribe to `documentClick$` and whenever this (`documentClick$`) emits, re-subscribe to `source`.

Did you want to do more with that? I didn't fully understand your last paragraph.

In my little example, where a mouse click is faked by a timer, I get an emission every 2 seconds:

```
import { of, repeat, timer } from 'rxjs';

const source = of('Repeat message');
const documentClick$ = timer(2000);

const result = source.pipe(repeat({ delay: () => documentClick$ }));

result.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Uff... that's a new record on "to simple to be true". :D I just hope they update the documentation to reflect that delay accepts a notifier and not just a number or date. Or is it using the event emitter in place of the optional asyncScheduler? Anyway, the documentation could be a tad clearer on that. :D

Comment: Yes, indeed :D You're right, there's not much information on this, they should have added such an example to their deprecation notes.